# can we use response enity to handle exception instead of custom expection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

can we use response entity to handle exception or error messages instead of using custome exception with the help of exception handler.
eg: in controller class:

```
code 1:
try {
    if(userId>10) {
     return new ResponseEntity<>("user id not found",HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(user,HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}catch(Exception e)
{
    return new ResponseEntity<>("any error message or error object",HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

code 2:

```
try {
    if(userId>10) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "No Records Found", e);
    }else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(user,HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}catch(Exception e)
{
    throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "No Records Found", e);
}

@ExceptionHandler({ResponseStatusException.class})
public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> handleOrderNotFoundException(ResponseStatusException ex){

    return new ResponseEntity<>(
        new ErrorMessage(ex.getMessage()) , HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

it seems both are same code 1 and code 2. which way should i use and why?
1.which approach should be used and why
2.if we use responsestatusException shall we need to handle in exception handler class.

Answer (score 0):

Functionally both ways would work, just `ResponseStatusException` is more readable in general.

Why do you set status to `HttpStatus.OK`? If you have an error you should response with apprioprate status.

Comment: How could u say response status exception is more readable. If both are similar then why we need custom exception. At least some advantage should be there right using custom or response status exception class.

Comment: In general it is. At least if you are ok with Spring default ExceptionHandler. Although if you use your own ExceptionHandler I would go for it and create a set of your custom exceptions.

Comment: I understood , still didn't got exact info
case 1:
createing custom exceptions like OrderNotFoundException , CustomerNotFoundException etc and invoke exception handler annotation with controller advice in that class.
case 2:
 using spring responseStatusException class and invoke exception handler annotation with controller advice in that class
case 3:
 creating only responseEnitity object and send to client even if occurs any excption or condition check like which mentioned in my first post.

above 3 ways we can handle. if all are same thn which one would be more advantage and why .

Comment: actually i serached lot of websites related to above topic i didnt get clear clarifications. what is the advantage using custom exception or responsestatus exception than the retuning respose enitity object directly

Comment: any other responses , waiting for your clarifications